# How can i merge these two queries to become one

Tags: mysql, laravel

The below code fetches branches of company

```
      $branches = DB::table('merchant')
     ->join('merchantlocation', 'merchantlocation.merchant_id', '=', 'merchant.id')
      ->join('location', 'location.id', '=', 'merchantlocation.location_id')
     ->where('merchant.company_id', '=', $id)
     ->whereNotNull('location.branch')
     ->get();
```

The below code is to fetch the sales of the branches

```
$receipt =DB::table('opos_itemdetails')
->join('opos_receiptproduct','opos_receiptproduct.id','=','opos_itemdetails.receiptproduct_id')
->join('product', 'product.id', '=', 'opos_receiptproduct.product_id')
->join('opos_receipt', 'opos_receipt.id', '=', 'opos_receiptproduct.receipt_id')
->join('opos_terminal', 'opos_terminal.id', '=', 'opos_receipt.terminal_id')
->join('location', 'location.id', '=', 'opos_terminal.id')
->sum('opos_itemdetails.price');
```

i would love to make the two query one so i can be able to pass it to my view as a single query

Comment: check what link b/w `opos_itemdetails` and `merchant` and add one more join

Comment: if i do that, i will only be able to get the sum of the price filled with out the details of the branch but i want to get the sum of the price fields and also the details of the branch